# Issue with reading and combining multiple weekly csv files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, concatenation, import-from-csv

So I have several years of weekly CSV files that look like, with in the form YYmmdd:

```
file = 'C:\\rig-070103'
```

I am trying to read and combine them into one dataset, preferably over a range of dates. So far I have:

```
pieces = []


for date in range(100):
    path = 'C:\\rig-YYmmdd.csv' % date
    frame = pd.read_csv(path)
    #frame['Date']= date
    pieces.append(frame)
    dataset = pd.concat(pieces, ignore_index=True)
print(dataset)

But this is giving me the error: 
path = 'C:\\rig-YYmmdd.csv' % date
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I know this has to do with how I am referencing each file, any suggestions? I would also like to create another column listing the date for each file loaded in, so 1 date repeated over all rows for each file. Any help on this is really appreciated!

Here is an example of the data:

```
Prov    Location    LSD Section Township    Range   Meridian ...
AB  00-00-006-29W4  0   0   6   29  4
AB  01-18-008-09W4  1   18  8   9   4
AB  05-10-008-10W4  5   10  8   10  4
AB  01-12-008-12W4  1   12  8   12  4
AB  09-23-008-26W4  9   23  8   26  4
AB  13-13-009-25W4  13  13  9   25  4
```

Comment: `range(100)` is just a range of integers from 0 to 100. Did you expect these to be dates?

Comment: No I just put something in there, I am not sure how to create a datetime range

Comment: looks like there's at least 3 questions all rolled into one.

Comment: I need to see the line that's throwing the error. This has turned into a text encoding issue. Post it on dropbox or something.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things going on here:

First, `for date in range(100)` will iterate through integers 0 through 99. No dates anywhere to be found.

Next, `path = 'C:\\rig-YYmmdd.csv' % date` isn't valid. *Assuming* you actually have a `datetime` object, you would do: `path = 'C:\\rig-%s.csv' % date.strftime('%y%m%d')`

Finally, you're writing/overwriting your dataframe with every iteration. That silly.

So you your code becomes

```
import pandas
pieces = []
columns = ['Prov', 'Objective', 'WellStatus', 'WellType']

for date in pandas.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=100):
    path = r'C:\rig-%s.csv' % date.strftime('%y%m%d')
    frame = pandas.read_csv(path, names=columns, encoding='utf-8')
    frame['date'] = date
    pieces.append(frame)

dataset = pandas.concat(pieces, ignore_index=True)
print(dataset)
```

Comment: Paul, is the idiom of putting the pieces into a list more desirably than incrementally appending each bit to an existing DataFrame? Lists expand more efficiently?

Comment: @JDLong -- I honestly have no clue. I was just going for minimal impact on the OP's code (i.e., indentation error vs a different operation). My guess is that pandas eventually has to loop through the elements itself, so you might as well do it your way.

Comment: Paul, I tried the following code but am getting the error:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2: invalid start byte

Comment: Damn. I was hoping for some deep magical reason to change my idiom. Because of my background with R I keep wanting to preallocate the dataframe somehow then add to it incrementally.

Comment: @carevans88 that's an issue w/ your data, try: `pandas.read_csv(path, names=columns, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Also, with iterating over 100 days, there must be a work around considering I intend to pull in 1 csv file per week for about 7 years.

Comment: @JDLong, I'd keep doing it your way -- I wasn't clear: my bet is that your way is faster.

Comment: @carevans88 did you try the fix that I suggested?

Comment: Yes shows this error again: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2: invalid start byt

Comment: I can't help you further without seeing the data. @carevans88

Comment: Ive added an example of what the csv looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65232/discussion-between-carevans88-and-paul-h).

Comment: You ALWAYS want to append to a list, then concat in one go. see the end of the first section: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few things you're doing here. One is you need a date range where each element is a day. That day then needs to be formatted as yymmdd. Then you pull in the csv into a dataframe. Then add a coumn for the date. Then append that to a main dataframe. Here's an attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

myDateList = pd.date_range('2003-01-01', periods=100)

myBigDf = pd.DataFrame()

for date in myDateList:
    path = 'C:\\rig-' + date.strftime('%y%m%d') + '.csv' 
    print path # show you what you got
    piece = pd.read_csv(path)
    piece['fileDate'] = date.strftime('%y%m%d')
    myBigDf.append(piece, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: To go back your question in the comment: I think it would be faster if you new ahead of time how my rows and columns the final data frame would have and said `myBigDf = pandas.DataFrame(index=range(n_rows), columns=list_of_columns)` and then appended to that.

Comment: yeah that lines up with my R intuition. I was just building a dummy test to verify this

Comment: hey JD, see jeff's comment on my post. apparently pandas `concat` function is smart enough that it's faster to append to the list (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects)

Answer (score 0):

As the traceback shows, it's not the right way to use the modulo operator on strings. You can use this tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html) to learn how it is used.

To get a string in the format yymmdd of a given date you can use the datetime module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and the "strftime" function of datetime.date like this:

```
from datetime import date 
d = date(2007, 1, 13)
filename = d.strftime("C://rig-%y%m%d.csv")
#filename will be "C://rig-070113.csv"
```

If you want an iteration over 100 consecutive days, you have to use datetime.timedelta:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
one_day = timedelta(1)
act_day = date(2007, 1, 13)
for i in range(100):
    filename = act_day.strftime("C://rig-%y%m%d.csv")
    ...
    act_day += one_day
```

Comment: You mean: `d = date(2007, 1, 13)` for 2007-Jan-13

Comment: Trying this solution, can you elaborate on the ... section.